# Looking for more elegant solutions

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and working on such a problem:

There are n numbered letters and n numbered envelopes. The letter x can't be
put into the envelope x.(OP only wants values where no value of x is at index x-1) What I want is to print out all the possible
cases.

The index of Array + 1 ---> the number of the envelop

The element of Array ---> the number of the letter

`Input:      n = 3.`

`Output:    [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]`

`Input:     n = 4.`

```
Output:   [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4, 2],
          [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1, 2],
          [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Here is my code:

```
$nums = []
def f( already, n, times )
  if n > times
    $nums << already.dup
    return
  else
    1.upto(times) do |i|
      next if ((already.include? i) || n == i)
      already << i
      f( already, n+1, times )
      already.pop
    end
  end
end
```

I'm looking for more elegant solutions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what real-world problem does this solve (if any)?

Comment: Why doesn't the output for n = 3 include [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]? Why doesn't the output for n = 4 include 23 elements?

Comment: @sawa: I'm thinking the OP only wants values where _no_ value of `x` is at index `x-1` - that would disqualify `[3,2,1]` since 2 is at index 1.  Hence my modified suggestion.  Would be nice to have some clarity on this, since the suggested output would still be incorrect as the OP has it.

Comment: @PinnyM You point out what I mean. Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @PinnyM I don't know any real-world problem can be solved by this. I read it from my math book.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) enumerator, rejecting all those where the value at index `x-1` matches `x`:

```
def f(n, x)
  (1..n).to_a.permutation.reject{|p| p[x-1] == x}
end

> f 3, 3
  => [[1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]] 
> f 4, 4
  => [[1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [2, 4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at your question again, it's unclear if you want to use a specific `x`, or just that the logic should hold true for any value of `x`.  If the second guess is what you want, then use this instead:

```
def f(n)
  (1..n).to_a.permutation.reject{|p| p.any?{|x| p[x-1] == x}}
end

> f 3
  => [[2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]] 
> f 4
  => [[2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Wow, that's a freaky cool feature that I didn't realize existed.